# FireFox events do not bubble or propagate from shadow to light DOM

Tags: firefox, dom-events, shadow-dom, custom-element, event-propagation

***EDIT 4***

Ok, I hope this additional info seals it.

Firefox DOES bubble the synthetic CLICK that I generate on SPACEBAR / ENTER, but it DOES NOT bubble the mouse CLICK.

CHROME, OPERA, and EDGE work as expected. (both events bubble)

All Browsers bubble INPUT events for both mouse and synthetic clicks.

Both events are COMPOSED, CANCELLABLE, and BUBBLE.

The only difference I have seen is the synthetic CLICK event has had its TARGET set to ABC-TOGGLE#myToggle whereas the TARGET for the mouse CLICK is still input checkbox.

Note: I do understand that SPACEBAR is normally a first class CLICK event for checkboxes but I have stopPropagation() for uniformity with CR.

Why won't the mouse CLICKs traverse the DOMs?

***END EDIT 4***

**EDIT 3**

Ok, I'm an idiot! Never knew spacebar *is* an intrinsic click :-(

**END EDIT 3**

**EDIT 2**

More info: Chrome triggers both a Click and an Input event in that order. Firefox agrees with spacebar/synthetic event but won't surface a Click to the light DOM when the mouse is clicked.

[This](https://richardmaher.github.io/CustElements/test_toggle.html) now works for FireFox and Chrome both TickBox and Toggle. But the SpaceBar CarrriageReturn functionality does not work. Still on it.

**END EDIT 2**

**EDIT 1**

Firefox does in fact bubble an event through to the light DOM but it is an INPUT event; not a CLICK event. Why?

**END EDIT 1**

The documentations says events triggered on elements in the Shadow DOM that make up a Web Component should pass from shadow to light DOM with the target, currentTarget, originalTarget et al coalesced into the Web-Component tagName, id, and so on.

This is not happening with FireFox in this [exaple](https://richardmaher.github.io/CustElements/test_toggle.html)

in test_toggle.html I wish to be notified of a "click" event on my "disTick" tickbox so that I can disable the Toggle: -

```
            document.getElementById("disTick").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                            if (e.target.checked)
                                myToggle.disabled=true;
                            else
                                myToggle.disabled=false;
                        });
                        
            document.body.addEventListener("change", (e) => {console.log("****"+e.target.tagName);});
```

It gets called on Chrome, Edge, Opera, but not FireFox.

(I have tried to trap click, input, and chang events on BODY but nothing bubbles.)

Curiously enough, my synthetic event does bubble up (from toggle.js)

```
    this.#toggle.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
            if (e.altKey || e.ctrlKey || e.isComposing || e.metaKey || e.shiftKey)
                return;
            
            if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 13)
            {
                console.log("key = " + e.keyCode);
                e.preventDefault();
                this.#toggle.click();   
            }
        });
```

What am I missing/ Why isn't the original click bubbling through light DOM on FireFox?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: See the F12 Console of https://toggle-switch.github.io/ I made an attempt at refactoring your code to make DOM creation and Event handling easier. I don't get the details of your _attribute_ handling, seems like a lot of boilerplate to change an _attribute_ HTH

Comment: See the console difference for Chromium and FireFox. We need a Safari output to check which one of the 2 is (more) right before a bug report can be filed

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code: https://toggle-switch.github.io/
To make DOM creation and Event handling easier.
But I probably did not get all your *attribute* handling right

Added warnings:

[image]

#### Chromium output:

[image]

#### FireFox output:

[image]

We need to check against Safari to determine which of the 2 are "right"

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply @Danny. The Xbrowser event handling is not an issue anymore (see the switch statement at line#115 in toggle.js BTW, according to caniuse.com FF is the only browser to use originalTarget)

The issue now (see EDIT 1) is FF converting a CLICK event to an INPUT event when it bubbles through the osmosis layer to the light DOM. My synthetic CLICK event for ARIA stays as a click so I'll probably single path the code to that. But it's annoying and YES I'd very much link to know what Safari does!