Web Component attributeChangedCallback not called for DISABLED attribute
How can my custom-element / web-component detect a DISABLED attribute change?
static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['checked', 'disabled', 'value'];
}

My  attributeChangedCallback() is not called?

That should just work™ https://jsfiddle.net/5132zr9f/ Are you extending another constructor than HTMLElement? Are you using the form related internals of your element? Basically, can you please share a [MRE]?

Wow, thanks for the quick answer!  I can provide a SSCCE but you've given me enough proof to go on to the bigger picture. My original question was down to a school-boy error on my behalf (forgetting disabled="false" still means DISABLED) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78138609/firefox-events-do-not-bubble-or-propagate-from-shadow-to-light-dom but in that code I don't get the attributedChangedCallback on the Toggle :-( anyway I'll ask the bigger question of why FF is correct at stopping CLICK events at the shadowRoot but why everyone still bubbles INPUT events from a DISABLED web component

https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5886

Good link! Will read. Change your code to property .disable=true rather than setAttrinute("disabled", "blah") and you'll see what I mean

But why would .disabled do anything here? My element is not deriving anything for an input or any other element that would have such an IDL attribute.

I don't understand :-( Are you saying "setAttribute("disabled") is perfectly reasonable but .disabled is stupid?

Not "stupid", but probably misled. .disabled, just like the "official" disabled attributes only exists on a bunch of elements (mainly form controls). For instance on a <div> it will return undefined, and setting it won't do nothing, but on an <input> it will return a boolean, and setting it will set the attribute. Your custom-element is like a div here, it doesn't know about this IDL attribute.

But my component HAS a tickbox input element

First, you don't show it, so we can't be talking about the same thing, because I'm no medium. And then, does it "have" it as in one of its children is an input, or "is" it one itself as in you declare its class with extends HTMLInputElement and then use is? If the former, it's still just like a div.  Note that the latter will not work in Safari.

It's the first. Thanks. Please note that FireFox behaves correctly by stopping click events from bubbling out of the shadow DOM if my component is disabled. Strangely both Chrome and FireFox allow sub-element input events to bubble and provide a complete composedPath(). I will update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78138609/firefox-events-do-not-bubble-or-propagate-from-shadow-to-light-dom soon.

You can declare disabled as getter/setter property on your Web Component
For the elements that do not have a disabled property by default:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled


<my-element disabled  ></my-element>
<script>
  function log(...args) {
    console.log(...args)
  }
  customElements.define('my-element',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      static get observedAttributes(){
        return ["disabled"];
      }
      attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue){
       log("attributeChanged",name,oldValue,newValue)
      }
      connectedCallback() {
        log("connectedCallback");
        this.disabled  = !this.disabled;
      };
      get disabled(){
        log("GET disabled", this.hasAttribute("disabled"));
        return this.hasAttribute("disabled");
      }
      set disabled(v){
        log("SET disabled", v);
        this.toggleAttribute("disabled",v);
      }
    });
</script>





The setter is slightly off. It should look like this: set disabled(v) { this.toggleAttribute('disabled', v); }.
